# ConfigWriter throws configparser.NoSectionError

Tags: python, configuration-files

I want to write a Configwriter that writes data from a dictionary to a config file.

```
jobstore = {
    'DEFAULT': [
        'foo',
        'bar'
    ],
    'DEFAULT2': [
        'foo',
        'bar'
    ]

}
with open('./config2.txt', 'w') as f:
    conf = ConfigParser()
    for job in jobstore.keys():
        conf.set(job, 'module', jobstore[job][0])
        conf.set(job, 'action', jobstore[job][1])
    conf.write(f)
```

If I try to execute this it throws

```
  File "C:\Python34\lib\configparser.py", line 879, in set
    raise NoSectionError(section)
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'DEFAULT2'
```

However it works if the dictionary only has 1 entry. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor for configparser.ConfigParser from  https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser-objects

```
class configparser.ConfigParser(defaults=None, dict_type=collections.OrderedDict,
                                allow_no_value=False, delimiters=('=', ':'), 
                                comment_prefixes=('#', ';'), inline_comment_prefixes=None,
                                strict=True, empty_lines_in_values=True,
                                **default_section=configparser.DEFAULTSECT**, 
                                interpolation=BasicInterpolation())
```

It works with the "DEFAULT" key because t has a default_section parameter, which creates a default section called "DEFAULT".
It can be verifed as below

```
>>> import configparser
>>> configparser.DEFAULTSECT
'DEFAULT'
```

So you have to manually create a new section called "DEFAULT2".

If you want to ensure that such an error should never be raised **and** you trust the data, you could do something like:

```
for job in jobstore.keys():
    if not conf.has_section(job):
        conf.add_section(job)
    conf.set(job, 'module', jobstore[job][0])
    conf.set(job, 'action', jobstore[job][1])
```

Comment: If I use this, I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 20, in <module>
    conf.add_section(job)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\configparser.py", line 1174, in add_section
    super().add_section(section)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\configparser.py", line 631, in add_section
    raise ValueError('Invalid section name: %r' % section)
ValueError: Invalid section name: 'DEFAULT'

Comment: Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.add_section

Comment: but add_section shouldn't even get executed in this case.

Comment: The solution was right there. Read the docs carefully. https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.has_section

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the section `DEFAULT2` before trying to add options to it. `DEFAULT` is automatically created when the `ConfigParser` object is initialized.

```
for job, (module, action) in jobstore.items():
    if job != 'DEFAULT':
        conf.add_section(job)
    conf.set(job, 'module', module)
    conf.set(job, 'action', action)
```